# sqlite3 query response very slow

Tags: database, sqlite

I have the following query which gives me the right result but at the cost of over 3 seconds. it is pretty slow in processing the result. Are there any optimization techniques that can be applied to this query to improve the performance/response time say < 1sec.

```
select dept, location , count(*) total from 
(
    select empName, dept, location  from companyTable t1 where  (position = 'manager' or position = 'supervisor' )and  dateTime in 
    (
        select max(dateTime) from companyTable t2 where t2.empName = t1.empName and location = 'Dallas'   and dateTime like '2016:09:05%' 
    )
    union all

    select empName, dept, location from companyTable t10 where  (position = 'manager' or position = 'supervisor')and dateTime in 
    (
        select min(dateTime) from companyTable t2 where t2.empName = t10.empName and location <> 'Dallas'  and dateTime like '2016:09:05%' 
    )
) 
group by dept, empName having count(empName) > 1;
```

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE companyTable
( dept varchar(32),location varchar(30),empName varchar(32), position varchar(30), dateTime time,
Primary key (dept, empName ,location ,position) );
```

***EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN***

```
2|0|0|SCAN TABLE companyTable AS t1
2|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE companyTable AS t2 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_companyTable_1 (dept=?)
4|0|0|SCAN TABLE companyTable AS t10
4|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 5
5|0|0|SEARCH TABLE companyTable AS t2 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_companyTable_1 (dept=?)
1|0|0|COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 4 (UNION ALL)
0|0|0|SCAN SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Comment: Show the DB schema and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Please note schema and explain query plan is updated.

Comment: ask at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The query and the EQP output do not match (and there are two `t2` aliases).

Comment: Please explain what this query is trying to accomplish. Are you searching for employees that have been both in Dallas and elsewhere at the same day?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I have corrected it. Basically I am trying to find the number of new employees relocated to 'Dallas' on a particular date.